# How to perform sorting on array list on different criteria

Tags: sorting, collections, arraylist

I have a class say

```
Class Ticket{


int id;
String status;
String assignedTo;

}
```

I have a arrayList , containing Ticket class object, now i want to sort this arryList on differnt criteria,ie. once on basis of id, sometimes on basis of status.

How can i do it,please suggest

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into the comparable method of the ArrayList class. You will need to overide this to be able to compare tickets and which order to sort them in. Then from somewhere in your code you will need to call Collections.sort() to sort the Tickets.